# Compatibility matrix between androidx libraries

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

Where can I find which versions of the various androidx libraries are compatible with each other?  Is there a matrix somewhere that shows which versions of androidx.lifecycle are compatible with androidx.naviation and androidx.compose?  If not, what exactly is the process for determining which versions to use?